# Converting subsripts and indices

Tags: matlab, indexing, mask, subscript, roi

I'm having a hard time figuring out transformation between spaces using ind2sub and sub2ind. Could someone help? The problem is as follows:

I have a mask **Y** (or region-of-interest) in which voxel values are either 1 or zero: **Y=72x72x33 double**. I then find all the voxels with value of 1 (there are 15 of them) then use ind2sub to get the x y z coordinates for these voxels:

```
indx = find(Y>0);
[x,y,z] = ind2sub(size(Y),indx); 
XYZ = [x y z]';
```

Since there are 15 voxels with the value of 1, I end up with **XYZ=3x15 double**, containing coordinates of these 15 voxels, something like this:

```
25 26 24 25 26 ...26
28 28 29 29 29 ...30
8  8  8  8  8  ...9
```

Based on some arbitrary criteria, I remove 6 voxels so **XYZ** become **3x9 double**. Let's call this **new_XYZ**. Now I would like to transform this **new_XYZ** back into a mask (let's call it **new_Y**). I tried this:

```
new_Y=sub2ind(size(Y),new_XYZ);
```

Here, I probably did something wrong with the sub2ind since new_Y didn't give me what I expected. The dimensions are also not 72x72x33. The old mask is a sphere so I expect the new mask to be close to that. Instead, I get a straight line. Can someone help me with the transformation?

Thanks.

A.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of things wrong in your approach. To detail I'll use a slightly smaller sample data set, but the explanation can scale up to any size.

```
Y = randi(10,5,5,3)-5 ;
```

This create a `5x5x3` containing random integers numbers from -5 to 5 (so a good chance to have about half of them positive (>0).

Before I go further, you can get a direct mask of your condition in the same shape of your matrix:

```
mask_positive_Y = Y>0 ;

>> whos mask_positive_Y
  Name                 Size             Bytes  Class      Attributes
  mask_positive_Y      5x5x3               75  logical
```

This gives you an array of logical (boolean), the same size of your matrix, containing 0 (`false`) everywhere and 1 (`true`) where your condition is validated (`Y>0`).

If you can work directly with this mask, you do not need to use `ind2sub` and `sub2ind` back and forth. For example, doing `Y(mask_positive_Y) = NaN;` would replace all the values indicated by the mask with `NaN`.

Since you want to modify the mask (remove some points), you may still need to get their indices, in which case you can simply call:

```
indx = find( mask_positive_Y ) ; %// will give the same result as: indx = find(Y>0);
```

Now let's assume you got your indices the way you specified, removed the 6 points and got your `new_XYZ` matrice. The way to rebuild the mask is as follow.

`ind2sub` gave you 3 vectors as output, and right enough, `sub2ind` will expect 3 vectors as input (not a 3 column matrix as you did). So you will have to decompose your `new_XYZ` into 3 vectors before you send it to `sub2ind`.

```
new_indx = sub2ind(size(Y), new_XYZ(:,1) , new_XYZ(:,2) , new_XYZ(:,3) );
```

But don't forget that you did transpose your result matrix when you did `XYZ = [x y z]';`, so make sure your `new_XYZ` is also transposed back with `new_XYZ = new_XYZ.' ;` before you decompose it in the code line above (or simply send the lines of `new_XYZ` instead of the columns as showed).

By the way, the proper `transpose` shorthand notation is `.'` (and not simply `'` which is the `Complex conjugate transpose`).

Now this `new_indx` is only a new vector of **linear indices**, homogeneous to the `indx` you had earlier. You could already use this to assign values under the mask, but if you want a new mask the same shape than your matrix `Y`, you have to go a bit further:

```
new_Ymask = false( size(Y) ) ;  %// build an empty mask (false everywhere)
new_Ymask(new_indx) = true ;    %// assign true to the masked values
```

This will be the same size as your initial matrix `Y`, but also the same size as the first boolean mask I showed you `mask_positive_Y`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer as well as the clear explanation, Hoki! This is why I love stackoverflow.